# I am using jmeter for socketcluster connection. Facing issues

Tags: jmeter

By using `websocket` open connection sampler I am making `socketcluster` connection. I am getting response code as 101 and response message as switching protocols and response headers as:

```
Response headers:
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 8i/hUMajQLY5hYfg0hq9z1U1HxI=
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
WebSocket-Server: uWebSockets
```

I am not able to find whether it is making connection in server. In server side I am not able to see active users. Throwing some error like below:

> 1524146177889 - Origin: Worker (PID 14262)    [Warning]
>   SocketProtocolError: Socket hung up
>       at SCSocket._onSCClose (/home/centos/jioplay/node_modules/socketcluster/node_modules/socketcluster-server/scsocket.js:240:17)
>       at WebSocket.internalOnClose (/home/centos/jioplay/node_modules/socketcluster/node_modules/socketcluster-server/scsocket.js:75:10)
>       at process.nextTick (/home/centos/jioplay/node_modules/uws/uws.js:445:27)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9

Please find attached files regarding script and results tree [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUYhA.png).